# How to replace empty cells in csv by other csv file?

Tags: csv

I have 2 CSV files with the same columns name i.e:
first csv:

```
Name    Age
Alex    18
Yana    20
Nate    22
```

second csv (age column is empty):

```
Name    Age
Alex    
Yana    
Nate
```

How to write batch script which will update empty column in the second csv by the first csv values?

Thanks

Comment: When you say "batch script" - do you mean inside Excel or using a scripting language like python / perl / etc

Comment: i mean to excel, but bat file which will do this action is fine as well